# Mongodb group joining two collection

Tags: mongodb

I know that it is possible with map reduce ([reference](http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/)), but I was wondering if it possible to using group (specifically, in the `keyf` function) to join 2 collections.

```
MYCOLL.collection.group(:keyf => "function(doc) { var var2Item=db.mycoll2.find({\"_id\":doc.my_sub_id}); var2=var2Item.join_var; return {'myreturn': doc.var1 + var2 }; }",     
:initial => { :r => 0 }, 
:reduce => "function(doc,prev) { prev.r += +1; }", 
:cond => {( ...my_conditions...)})
```

I have also tried

```
var2=doc.my_sub_id.join_var
```

and neither seems to work. I am using the Ruby Driver, but it is not really important, as the query is (practically) raw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to join two collections by using the "group" function.  The group function is intended for aggregation, the cond query expression is used to select documents, the key expression or keyf function provides the grouping, the initial expression and reduce function process the group, and the finalize function allows you to process each item in the aggregation result.

Note that the aggregation "group" function is for a single collection, i.e., all of the data is from a single collection.  In the map-reduce reference, the equivalent of a join is the result of mapping two collections to common keys and a common output collection while running the reduce function on the output collection.

You can verify for yourself that the find function is undefined in the context of running the group function on the server by using the mongo shell to run the following.

```
db.coll.remove();
db.coll.insert({a: 1, b: 2});
printjson(db.coll.group(
    {
        keyf: function(doc) { return {x: db.coll.find({a: true})}; },
        reduce: function(doc,prev) { prev.r += 1; },
        initial: { r: 0 }
    }));
```

The result is:

```
[ { "x" : "DBQuery: test.coll -> undefined", "r" : 1 } ]
```